# On exponentials of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation

> How can I prove that $|e^{A}|\leq e^{|A|}$ where $|\cdot|$ means the operator norm of matrices?

I guess i'm having trouble with the definition!

A is a square (complex or real) matrix.

Comment: is $|\cdot|$ the determinant ? And what have you tried ?

Comment: I would assume that $|A|=(A^*A)^{1/2}$.

Comment: I wrote a counter example assuming $|\cdot|$ is a determinant.

Comment: I think writing $|A|$ for $\det A$ would be perverse.

Comment: @harald i saw it several times before

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I am aware that perverse people exist, yes. Right now we are learning from another answer that a matrix norm might be the intended meaning. More perversion! The result is wrong if my guess is taken, by the way. An easy counterexample is $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$.

Comment: I think he uses it for the linear operator norm

Comment: Yes, I meant the vertical bar to be the norm operator, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\|.\|$ be a sub multiplicative norm on $\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ (ie. $\|AB\|\le\|A\|\|B\|$). The matrix exponential for an element $A\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ is defined as follows. $e^A:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{A^k}{k!}$. To show the inequality, we first show $\|A^k\|\le\|A\|^k$ by induction. Then:

$\|e^A\|=\|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{A^k}{k!}\|=\|\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{A^k}{k!}\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{A^k}{k!}\| \le\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\|\frac{A^k}{k!}\| \le\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\|A\|^k}{k!}=e^{\|A\|}$

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong!

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}100&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $|A|=0$ so $e^{|A|}=1$. But 
$$
e^{A}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{100}&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
so $|e^{A}|=e^{100}>1=e^{|A|}$.

Comment: i fixed it the redundant A